# More Accurate StopWatch (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, timer, stopwatch

Is there any sort of "sleep" method that is more accurate than the stopwatch? Or, is there a way to make the stopwatch class more accurate? It doesn't have to be in .NET, it can be in c++, but whatever language it is in has to have exactly 1ms accuracy; I don't need more then that. Say if I want my program to "sleep" for 300ms, I would like it to sleep for 300ms at least most of the time.

Currently I use:

```
Dim StopWatch As New StopWatch
StopWatch.Start
Do
Loop Until StopWatch.ELapsed.Milliseconds >= 300
StopWatch.Stop
```

My results running it 5 times were: 306, 305, 315, 327, 304.

It stayed like that if I ran it more.

I put my thread and process priority on "Realtime" / "High".

Comment: I remember reading about an alternatie to stopwatch in: http://www.amazon.de/Microsoft-Visual-Basic-2010-Entwicklerbuch/dp/3866455356/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1355735382&sr=8-2
Your could also try: http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/util/StopWatches.html

Comment: @ChristianSauer: All "alternatives" to Stopwatch (which I know) are simply doing the same, what the Stopwatch class does: Using the HPET if available. And most of them where "invented" in Framework 1.1 times, because the Stopwatch class came only in FW 2.0. The Stopwatch class IS accurate - IF the HPET is available. If no HPET, then I dont know any alternative that could produce a similar accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

The Stopwatch class has a property `IsHighResolution`. If it returns ´true´ you are using the **High Performance Event Timer** (HPET) - availability depends on hardware and OS. Using this, you can measure times very accurate. BUT! Windows (as usual Linuxes) is NOT a realtime OS, but uses preemptive multitasking. Whenever the OS thinks, that it needs to, it will put your current thread `on hold` to do other work and after some time, it will `return` to your thread and let it continue. If this `switch` happens somewhere inside your loop, you still measure the correct time, but it contains an amount of `inactivty` time.

Since a `time slice` under Windows is something between 15 and 30 ms, you(r thread) might be suspended after 299 ms and 15-30 ms later you will get back. And that's the effect you see. The Stopwatch IS accurate. It just measures stuff you didn't expect.

How to overcome: You can't. As said: Windoes IS NOT a realtime OS! Even if you assign priority "realtime" to your process.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is completely normal. Delay will never be exactly 300ms, it will always be more than that. Sleep itself is accurate, but the actual delay depends on your operating system, and other processes running in parallel to yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more accurate timer, you need to use the current date and time as a reference. Here is a simple equation that you can run every millisecond:

`currentTime - startTime = elapsedTime`

...where `currentTime` is `System.DateTime.Now`, `startTime` is the time that the timer was started, and `elapsedTime` is a `System.DateTime.TimeSpan`.

For more details on how to do this, check out the source of a program I made in VB.Net, E-Tech Timer: http://etechtimer.codeplex.com